# ng-keypress event not fired from email input tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm experimenting with angular JS, and I'm trying to get the `ng-keypress` event working. My HTML looks like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/orders" class="new_order" id="new_order" method="post" ng-controller="OrderCreateController">
   <div class="new-invitee"><input id="new_invitee" name="new_invitee" ng-keyup="addNewInvitee($event)" placeholder="Add email addresses here..." required="required" type="email" /></div>
</form>
```

And the controller looks like:

```
  app.controller('OrderCreateController', function($scope, $http, $element) {
    $scope.invitees = [];
    return $scope.addNewInvitee = function($event) {
      var el, isValid;
      isValid = $event.target.validity.valid;
      el = $($event.target.parentElement);
      el.toggleClass('valid', isValid);
      el.toggleClass('invalid', !isValid);
      if ($event.which !== 13 || !isValid) {
        return;
      }
      $scope.invitees.push({
        name: $event.target.value
      });
      return $event.preventDefault();
    };
  });
```

But the controller method is never getting called. Any ideas why?

Comment: I think addNewInvitee needs to be a directive

Comment: Thanks @koolunix it does indeed work as a directive, but it seems odd that ng-keypress, ng-keyup and ng-keydown don't work in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

**Option 1:** Remove the ' action="/orders" ' from your form tag, and all runs fine.

**Option 2:** Rewrite your code as such:

```
app.controller('OrderCreateController', function($scope, $http, $element) {
  $scope.invitees = [];
  return $scope.addNewInvitee = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault(); // stripped return from the preventDefault and moved to the top. 
    var el, isValid;
    isValid = $event.target.validity.valid;
    el = angular.element($event.target.parentElement);
    el.toggleClass('valid', isValid);
    el.toggleClass('invalid', !isValid);
    if ($event.which !== 13 || !isValid) {
      return;
    }
    $scope.invitees.push({
      name: $event.target.value
    });
    console.log("I just ran!", $scope.invitees); // Sanity check
  };
});
```

Both of these options are running just fine on my end, hope it all works out for you.

Good luck :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. My problem is that the `addNewInvitee` method isn't being called at all. Neither of the changes you have suggested appear to resolve that issue, though I'm curious to know what effect removing the 'action="/orders"' from the form tag should have had?

Comment: Removing the 'action="/orders"' would render the form tag not having a default event, so in this context it would be another way of saying 'preventDefault'. As far as I'm concerned, this is the end result anyway.

I'm curious as to why this is working just fine on my end and not so much on yours. Might be a silly question, but what version of Angular are you using if I may ask?